# Set a culture on c# backend page

Tags: c#, culture, uiculture

I'm trying to set the culture and culture ui in the Page_Load of a .aspx.cs page. I have tried

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
```

and

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

and

```
Culture = "fr-CA";
UICulture = "fr-CA";
```

but none of them work.
Does anyone know how to set the culture and uiculture?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you expect to happen and what did happen? How did you test?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I am using resx files which use the current culture to display the page in the required language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: override the InitializeCulture. This is what it looks like when I incorporated cookies and use the current cookie to set the language of the page.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CurrentLanguage"];
        if (!IsPostBack && cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            if (cookie.Value.ToString() == "en-CA")
            {
               // currently english
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
            else
            {
               //currently french
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
        }
    }
```